# Is there a way to call parent’s method from a child when the method doesn’t belong to parent's prototype?

Tags: javascript

I’ve understood how to call parent’s method when the method resides in the parent’s prototype.
However, is there a way to call parent’s method when it doesn’t belong to its prototype?

Let’s say we have the following sample:

```
(function () {
    function Parent() {
        this.myMethod2  = function(){
            return 'Parent' + this.test;
        };
    }
    Parent.prototype.myMethod = function () {
        return 'Parent ' + this.test;
    };

    function Child() {
        Parent.call(this);
        this.myMethod  = function(){
            return 'Child >> ' + Parent.prototype.myMethod.call(this);
        };
        this.myMethod2  = function(){
            return 'Child >> ' + Parent.myMethod2.call(this); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
        };
    }

    var c = new Child();
    c.test = 'test';
    console.log(c.myMethod());
    console.log(c.myMethod2());
})();
```

Here **c.myMethod()** does its work fine.

However **c.myMethod2()** causes an error *“Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined”*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about :

```
 function Parent() {
    this.myMethod2  = function(){
        return 'Parent' + this.test;
    };
}

function Child() {
    Parent.call(this);

    var old = this.myMethod2;
    this.myMethod2  = function(){
        return 'Child >> ' + old.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

Explanation : when you store a fonction in a field; it behave exactly as a normal object, so if reaffect a new value, you need to have a reference to the old one. This is what happens when things aren't stored in the prototype.

Edit : i added the arguments in the apply. Apply has the adavantage to be able to call a function with the args specified as an array. "Arguments" is a predefined name that store the arguments pass to the current fonction, usefull for varargs, or overloading like this.

Comment: It's so easy... Thanks! :)

Comment: No problem, don't forget to accep the answer so people will know the problem is resolved

Comment: Btw, sorry, I don’t understand why people prefer to use parent’s prototype for such a case. Can you tell me what’s the pros?

Comment: this.myMethod will create a new instance of the function for each new instance of type parent (or child). So if you create quite a lot of element, you'll waste quite a lot of memory. Since i use angular which already make most of my objects singleton, i don't really get to tuse prototype a lot myself